# Cascade Dropdown with empty values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, entity-framework, cascadingdropdown

I use Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC + Angular project and there is a cascade dropdown with the following data and when creating a Ticket, these dropdown values are stored in the Ticket table.

***Parent Entity:***

```
|  Id  |  Name          | 
-------------------------
|  0   |  N/A          |
|  1   |  Software      |
|  2   |  Hardwire      |
|  3   |  System        |
|  4   |  Electricity   |
-------------------------
```

***Child Entity:***

```
|  Id  |  MasterId  |  Name          | 
--------------------------------------
|  0   |     0      |  N/A           |
|  1   |     1      |  Java          |
|  2   |     1      |  C#            |
|  3   |     2      |  Monitor       |
|  4   |     2      |  Keyboard      |
|  5   |     3      |  EMail         |
|  6   |     3      |  Antivirus     |
|  7   |     3      |  Operating Sys.|
--------------------------------------
```

***Ticket Entity:***

```
|  Id  |  ParentId  |  ChildId  |  Subject  | 
---------------------------------------------
|  1   |     1      |     1     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  2   |     1      |     2     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  3   |     2      |     3     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  4   |     2      |     4     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  5   |     3      |     5     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  6   |     3      |     6     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  7   |     3      |     7     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  8   |     4      |     0     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  9   |     4      |     0     |  Xxxxxxx  |
|  10  |     4      |     0     |  Xxxxxxx  |
---------------------------------------------
```

There is some parent record(s) that does not have child record e.g. Electricity and for this reason I am planning to use the following approach:

***Scenario I:***
User select parent and then select corresponding child record from the cascade dropdowns. If there is no child of a parent record, the child dropdownlist will be hidden and ChildId set as 0 (zero) to the Ticket table. Because both ParentId and ChildId are required fields.

***Scenario II:*** However, I am not sure if this is a good approach for this scenario and think of that create another child record for the master record(s) that has not child record with the same name as shown below:

***Child Entity:***

```
|  Id  |  ParentId  |  Name          | 
--------------------------------------
|  ... |     ...    |  ...           |
|  8   |     4      |  Electricity   |
|  ... |     ...    |  ...           |
--------------------------------------
```

By doing this there will be no need to use parent6-child records with the Id of 0 and when user select Electricity as parent, the child dropdown will be list Electricity as child record (that can also be hidden) and ParentId-ChildId will be 4-8 in the Ticket table. Which scenario is better? Or is there a better scenario for this situation? Regards...

Comment: I would go with [scenario I] because it is cleaner  and easier to implement. Another option is to allow the ChildId column in the ticket table to be nullable and specify null values for parents with not children

Comment: @ShaiAharoni Thanks for reply. Actually in Scenario 2, ParentId and ChildId fields will be required as their values are available in the Parent and Child tables (for Electricity the ChildId value in teh Ticket will be 8 instead of 0 or null). On the other hand, there is another table for sending Email according to ChildId values and in this case if I use 0 in the Email table for ChildId value, I cannot determine the corresponding ticket type by using this ChildId. In this case may it be better to use Scenario II? What do you think?

Comment: Any reply regarding to this issue? I think it is a common scenario for such a kind of situations.

Comment: I would go with scenario 2 and create a generic label for those specific cases.

Comment: @iamdlm Could you pls explain a little bit more by posting a sample answer using my entities above?

Comment: I would just create a child for electricity with label '-' and disable that drop-down when selected (in my opinion it's UI friendlier than show/hide elements). And in your email table you have to include a column with parent and child IDs so you can navigate backwards between objects, in case you need it.

Comment: @iamdlm Do you mean navigate between Parent and Child entities by **"you can navigate backwards between objects"**? Thanks...

Comment: Yes, because from what I understood you only have a column for Child_Id in that Email table and you should, at least, have its immediate parent.